# Como abrir o formulário bootstrap modal depois de um erro de validação Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3, javascript-eventos

Tenho um formulário de contato em bootstrap modal. Tenho as validações onde estão validando corretamente. Agora minha pergunta é:
Como faço para quando não passar da validação ele voltar as mensagem no modal com ele aberto. 
Quando ele valida e não passa na validação ele não abre o modal. Assim o cliente nunca saberá que o formulário foi enviado
Como está minha chamada no modal: 
tenho uma View onde tenho o modal.blade.php no meu índex.blade.php eu dou um include nele e no meu botão onde ativa o modal esta assim:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal"  
        data-target="#product_view" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Clique aqui.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse butano chama o meu modal. 
Como faço para eu chamar esse modal no controller?

---

Comment: Coloque todo o código desde Controller, View e Javascript! dessa forma fica complicado dizer algo.

Comment: Cara eu não manjo de Jquery, mais olhando bem o pouquinho que eu conheço que é quase nada, pode reparar uma coisa. era somente fazer um 
@if(Session::has('errors'))
    e chamar o modal aqui hehehe.
@endif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, desculpe pela minha falta de atenção, mais realmente eu não tenho habilidades em JS. Então eu reparando o código, vi que ele retorna uma sessão com uma variável Errors. Então simplesmente eu dei um if verificando se existia mesmo essa variável de sessão. Veja:

```
@if(Session::has('errors'))
   e aqui dentro eu chamei o meu js.
@endif
```

Como eu disse por não saber muito de js, sei que tem como a pagina primeiro ser lida pra depois o javascript ser executado. Então logo eu fiz :

```
$(document).read(funciona(){
    alert('Ops!! Teve erros no seu formulário. Vamos abrir novamente para que você possa corrigir. ;) ');
    $('#product_view').modal('show');
 });
```

E assim resolvendo o meu problema.